# Not able to display the blob image dynamicaly from mysql database in itext table

Tags: java, spring-boot, itext

### I am trying to display an image from db in the itext table using below code

### DAO Class

```
    Blob imageBlob = rs.getBlob("VECHICLE_IMAGE");
    byte[] imgData = imageBlob.getBytes(1,(int)imageBlob.length());
    vechileDetailsReportBean.setVechileImageByte(imgData);
```

### Controller Class

```
   PdfPTable nestedTable = new PdfPTable(2);
   nestedTable.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Image")));    
   Image image = Image.getInstance(listVechileDetailsReportBean.get(i).getVechileImageByte());                  
   image.scaleAbsolute(300,300);
   nestedTable.addCell(new PdfPCell(image));
```

### DB Desc

```
enter code here
     [Vechile detail Table][1]

INS_AGENT   varchar(40) YES         
VECHICLE_IMAGE  mediumblob  YES         
VECHILE_TYPE    varchar(40) YES         
VECHILE_TYPEID  int(11) YES
```

### **Getting Below error**

```
       RegNo:::S234442::Image::com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Blob@22c4fafe
      java.io.IOException: The byte array is not a recognized imageformat.
      at com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(Image.java:473)
      at com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(Image.java:374)
```

Kindly suggest me how to display the image in itext from db dynamically

Comment: It sounds like the format of your image data is not recognized. What is their format?

Comment: tried with .jpg format.  And my pojo class is 
    @Lob
    @Column(name="VECHICLE_IMAGE")
    private byte[] image;

Comment: Have you already tried (as a test)  extracting the image manually and reading it using itext from the file system? If that works, then the blob / byte array doesn't correctly transport the image. If it doesn't work, there most likely is something weird with the image itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.. you are right.. The image was not stored properly in the db. Now its working fine. I am able to retrieve the image from database.

Comment: Great. I'll make that an actual answer you can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such a situation you should always first try (as a test) extracting the image manually and reading it using itext from the file system. If that works, then the blob / byte array doesn't correctly transport the image. If it doesn't work, there most likely is something weird with the image itself.